# How to insert large xmlType data from one table to another. ORA-19011: Character string buffer too small

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-insert, xmltype

I have to get data that is of type XMLType and to insert the same in another DB having the same table with the same XMLType column.

1. I'm reading data from here

```
select id, to_clob("CONTACT") as CONTACTNAME1
from CONTACT_BINARY_TBL
```

2. saving data in

```
insert into COPY_CONTACT_BINARY_TBL (ID,CONTACTNAME)
values (#ID#,#CONTACTNAME1#)
```

Results:

> java.sql.SQLException: ORA-19011: Character string buffer too small.

So, it works for small XML and not for large as 4K is the limit for vachar2.

So how can I insert the large xmlType value?

```
insert into contact_binary_tbl
values(1,XMLTYPE('....... ');
```

Comment: What is the structures of your table? You wrote `XMLType`, but the `ORA-19011` is about `varchar2`. And do you transfer your data through java? There should be `getClob` or `getCharacterStream` on fetch and set the same for insert.

Comment: Why are you reading and writing in two stages, and how are you holding/transforming/translating the values? If you can't do `insert ... select ...` as one operation, you can at least keep the value as a CLOB (or BLOB?) and use a bind variable for the insert, rather than building the insert with a quoted string literal? There isn't enough detail about your process to be more specific.

Comment: If you do not need to transform the data with some external tools and do not have network isolation, then the fastest and most reliable way to transfer data between two systems will be a [database link](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/CREATE-DATABASE-LINK.html#GUID-D966642A-B19E-449D-9968-1121AF06D793).

Answer (score 0):

```
I tried like below jar and it worked.

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
    <artifactId>xdb</artifactId>
    <version>10.2.0.2.0</version>
</dependency>
----------------------------------------------------------
In extractor class:

else if(OracleTypes.OPAQUE == colType){
                        // get the XMLType 
                        OPAQUE opaquexml = (OPAQUE)rs.getObject(j + 1); 
                        XMLType xt = null;
                        if(null != opaquexml) {
                            xt = XMLType.createXML(opaquexml);
                            rowMap.put(colNames[j], xt);
                        }
}
--------------------------------------------------------------------
In loader: where you set values in prepStmt
 else if (value instanceof XMLType) {
            pStmt.setObject(j, (XMLType)value);
        }
--------------------------------------------------------------------
pStmt.execute.
```